# IF ELSE statement SQLite

Tags: iphone, ios, sqlite, if-statement

Could anyone help me write up an If Else statement for iPhone's SQLite?

I need a:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ..... WHERE ... = '..') > 0 
BEGIN 
SELECT * FROM .... WHERE ... = '...' 
END
```

But I cannot get it to work. Is it even possible with SQLite.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  .... 
WHERE 
  ... = '...' 
  AND (SELECT COUNT (*) FROM ..... WHERE ... = '..') > 0
```

Comment: But this isnt an if else statement is it? I need to search a column if it returns 1 result. Otherwise it must search in other columns